# NextJs - How to remove duplicate URL from sitemap generator?

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, seo, sitemap

In NextJs app, I am using `nextjs-sitemap-generator` package to handle sitemap. Here I am trying to avoid some duplicate URLs, how can I add it in `ignoredPaths`.

Eg: I have `http://localhost/about/security` and `http://localhost/security`, I want to remove only `http://localhost/security`, so If I add `ignoredPaths: ['/security']` then both links will get remove.

Please help to solve this.

If I use `next-sitemap` package how can I do the same changes using `exclude` or other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex!

```
ignoredPaths: ["/admin", /^\/security/ ],
```